# ros/node_handle.h No such file ERROR in Arduino 'hellow world' tutorial

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38:29: fatal error: ros/node_handle.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96811/ros/node_handle.h-no-such-file-error-in-arduino-%27hellow-world%27-tutorial/) by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must run `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py PathToYourSketchbookLibraries` ?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on 2013-11-07**:
Thank you Balto for answering. I'm using ROS Fuerte. So there is no rosserial_arduino or I couldn't find it. Then I manually copy & paste the things inside ros_lib folder to /usr/share/arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ & gave permissions. Then it worked.

**Comment by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on 2016-04-10**:
Hasitha could you tell me what permissions you used to get it to run? I am having the same problem.